# Connect Spring MVC with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to connect my project with SQL database, but I have a problem with connection.

ERRORS:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml]
```

resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="haslo123" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webstore" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DispatcherServlet-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.packt.webstore"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

InMemoryProductRepository:

```
@Repository
public class InMemoryProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

    private List<Product> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();


    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public Product load() {
        Product product = entityManager.find(Product.class, "1");
        return product;
    }

    public InMemoryProductRepository() {

        listOfProducts.add(load());
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return listOfProducts;
    }
}
```

Product:

```
@Entity(name="Product")
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String productId;
@Basic
    private String name;
@Basic
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
@Basic
    private String description;
@Basic
    private String manufacturer;
@Basic
    private String category;

..
}
```

And I'm not sure if resource.xml is in the correct place:

[It's my project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e4Cz.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: resource.xml is in the META-INF folder .

Comment: You might be missing spring-data-jpa dependency

Comment: added and it not works

Answer (score 0):

It seems some missing dependency or have several Spring data Jar in your dependencies. Some of the spring jars contain meta info files with the same name. 
First try with  adding below dependence in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
```

if not resolved than follow below link
http://robert-reiz.com/2011/11/14/832/#comment-506

Answer (score 0):

why don't you configure the entityManager with in spring configuration like this ? it is more simple and donot require extra persistence.xml configuration for entityManager.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="12345" />
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="model-nadra" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```